# Get friendly disassemble hex file

Tags: disassembly, hex

I'd like to know if there is a way to have a more friendly way to get disassemble hex file coming from Adafruit board.

Let me explain actually I'm working with `Adafruit feather 32u4` running with `ATmega32u4` with `avr-dude` I got an `hex` file. After that I disassembled the file with `avr-objdump` but I got no friendly file, here is an example what I got

```
  b8:   11 24           eor     r1, r1
  ba:   1f be           out     0x3f, r1        ; 63
  bc:   cf ef           ldi     r28, 0xFF       ; 255
  be:   d8 e0           ldi     r29, 0x08       ; 8
  c0:   de bf           out     0x3e, r29       ; 62
  c2:   cd bf           out     0x3d, r28       ; 61
  c4:   21 e0           ldi     r18, 0x01       ; 1
  c6:   a0 e0           ldi     r26, 0x00       ; 0
  c8:   b1 e0           ldi     r27, 0x01       ; 1
  ca:   01 c0           rjmp    .+2             ;  0xce
```

My question : there is a way to have a more friendly disassemble file ? With label or something else ? Or with an hex file only brut assembly is available ?

Can I create object file from my disassemble hex file ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the hex file through a tool like IDA Pro (paid) or Ghidra as a more intelligent disassembler/decompiler. those tools try to generate pseudocode from the assembly, too and also try to detect where functions start and end.

Comment: I'll try Ghidra, but when I imported my hex file, for the langugage what should I select, I've multiple AVR8 available, maybe default AVR8 with gcc ?

Comment: yes, thats a good try for first. GCC is most common AVR compiler